# Picture element WebP flexing

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-images

Background: [Bootstrap 3 way of laying out 8 images in a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100988/)

I now know how to flex 3 images:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
img {
  width: 30%;
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/1024x768" />
<img src="https://placehold.it/1024x768" />
<img src="https://placehold.it/1024x768" />
```

But I want to introduce smaller **WebP** alternative images and I think you do that with the [picture element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element).

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: space-around;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
picture {
  width: 30%;
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="http://s.natalian.org/2015-12-12/1024x768.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/1024x768" />
</picture>

<picture>
  <source srcset="http://s.natalian.org/2015-12-12/1024x768.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/1024x768" />
</picture>

<picture>
  <source srcset="http://s.natalian.org/2015-12-12/1024x768.webp" type="image/webp" />
  <img src="https://placehold.it/1024x768" />
</picture>
```

However, I can't figure out how to make the CSS format the PICTUREs 3 abreast like they do with IMG. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a flex container only the child elements become flex items. Descendants beyond the children do not become flex items and flex properties don't apply to them.

In your [first example](http://jsfiddle.net/4ja95hma/), `body` is the flex container and `img` is the flex item.

In your second example, however, `body` is the flex container, `picture` is the flex item, and `img` is, well, nothing special in terms of flex. It's a normal inline element.

You'll need to make `picture` a (nested) flex container in order to apply flex properties to the image elements. But in your case, [this may not be necessary](http://jsfiddle.net/4ja95hma/1/).

Also note that the `picture` element is not universally supported yet (see [**caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#search=picture)).

Your first demo: [**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ja95hma/)

Your second demo, revised: [**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/4ja95hma/1/)

Comment: For the purpose of providing webp alternatives, `<picture>` support is sufficient. Only Safari 9 won't support it, so you can't use it for mime type switching for JPEG2000.